# start date and end date both are off by 1 day in Google Calendar

Tags: php, date, icalendar

I have some php code dynamically generating a .ics file for download. I am passing in a start date value of **08/01/2019** and when it succesfully gets imported into ical / google calendar it is off by one day, despite the epoch timestamp being correct. I am not sure what I am missing here.

I have tried reformatting the date to a different date string, than converting it to the format required for ical and that results in jan 1 1969. I am using the WordPress date_i18n() function to format the date in expected value.

```
$dateVal; // contains 08/01/2019    
$dtstart = date_i18n("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime( $dateVal) );

// output: 20190801T000000Z
```

When the event goes into the calendar, it shows my date as july 31st, 2019 at 6pm NOT the expected value of august 1st, 2019

Any ideas how I can debug this?

Comment: Maybe it's a timezone issue.

Comment: If not using GMT would think you need a timestamp. But I am sure it is 5:00 somewhere... Add some time aspect so you can see how many hours off you are.

Comment: @ficuscr if the date string doesn't have a time part isn't it assumed to be 00:00:00 by strtotime?

Comment: Would assume so. Leaving it off might just mean not seeing that when ical is parsed and rendered. Suggesting an explicit time of say 18:00 and easier to spot how the datetime is shifting to whatever offset.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm just thinking, `20190801T000000Z` is that date and time in Z. If you aren't in Z, the calendar is going to adjust the date/time to your timezone, right?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/#source Yikes. You tell me ;)

Comment: »`some php code`«, show it, maybe help isn't far…

Comment: daylightsavingtime

Comment: Guess we could look at the RFC... https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545 - anyway though, set a timezone or use GMT seems correct. We are sending a datetime to the client, have to be explicit as Don't Panic says it will adjust... Or everyone must reside in Greenwich?

Answer (score 1):

What *I think* is happening is this:

Your event is supposed to be at 8/01/2019 in your timezone, which based on the apparent offset seems to be UTC+6.

the `\Z` in your format string is indicating that the event is at 8/1/2019 in UTC, so when you see it on your calendar, it is adjusted to your timezone, so it gets 8 hours subtracted.

Try leaving off the `\Z`, I think it should just use your local timezone.

Or convert the time to UTC.

```
$date = new DateTime($dateVal);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dtstart = $date->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
```